# SwiftUI "ForEach" with inconsistent Data type and Closure Type, no compiler error generated? How does inference of type works in this case?

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols, type-inference, associated-types

Following code could be compiled and run without warning or message, but how can it work?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var lists = ["a", "b"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(lists, id: \.self) { (str: String?) in 
                if let str {
                    Text(str)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the lists conforms to `RandomAccessCollection<Element>` hence Element is inferred as String, but how can I pass a closure of type `(String?) -> some View` to ForEach? Shouldn't it only allow the closure of type `(String) -> Content` ?
Also in the description of RandomAccessCollection, why there are two Element type? One is passed as generic argument, and another one is an associated type. Are they considered as one type or two different types?

Comments:

The problem has been solved, this seems to be some sort of automatic sub-typing. Indeed, a more general argument will be true in swift. `T1->T2` is a subtype of `T3->T4` if and only if `T3` is a subtype of `T1` and `T2` is a subtype of `T4` (`T` is a subtype of `T` of course). Swift recognise `T` as a subtype of `T?`. It is intuitive but should be mentioned in the document.

For example, following code will be compiled without errors:

```
struct Solution {
    lazy var fun1: (Int) -> Any = fun2
    var fun2: (Any) -> Int
}
```

Comment: You can't use id: self you need to give an id property

Comment: This is unrelated to question. The code will compile without warning or errors. I should have made my problem be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about `ForEach` or `RandomAccessCollection` but about closures, you can apply the same definition of the closure parameter if you use `forEach` or `compactMap` etc on the `lists` array.

```
 ["a", "b"].forEach { (str: String?) in 
     if let str { print(str) }
 }
```

The closure is a function and when you define the parameter of this function to be `String?` then the compiler has no issue with passing `String` objects to the closure. The opposite would of course not work, defining the parameter as `String` and then trying to pass an optional value.

Comment: I think this is probably something of automatic sub-typing. It seems swift considers `String? -> Content` to be a subtype of `String -> Content`, implying `String` is a subtype `String?`. I am also supposing `T1->T2` is a subtype of `T3 -> T4` if `T3` is a subtype of `T1` and `T2` is a subtype of `T4`.